# Install location for apps on AWS RHEL if I want to have separate EBS volumes for OS and the apps

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I am new to both AWS and to custom crafting a linux environment, and am finding it difficult to get my head around how to have the OS and any installed packages/apps on separate EBS volumes (if that even is a good idea). This thought arose from an AWS best practices article: [Best Practices for Amazon EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-best-practices.html)

1. When they say "Use separate Amazon EBS volumes for the operating system versus your data", is this referring to the what would normally be in "/home", or would this apply to "/opt" as well? (... or none of the above)
2. What is the correct way to move /opt to a non-root volume in an EC2 context? Most guides I see show changes to /etc/fstab to have mounts made permanent but I am wary of doing this for EC2 because of root EBS volumes (usually) disappearing when instances are terminated.
3. If I was to go down the multiple volumes approach, what should be the minimum sizes of the 'default' (the one attached when launcing EC2 instance) RHEL v8 volume, and the other volumes.

Answer (score 1):

Where your data is and how big your volumes need to be is your decision. Separate data volumes allow mobility between instances, and easier resizing.

Conventions like the FHS leave entire trees under `/opt` for site local software or `/srv` for serving data. Remember you can also mount at deeper points of the tree, like `/var/lib/pgsql` or `/var/mail`.  `/home`, convenient for your users even if you don't need to put system service data there. Any or all of these can be data mount points.

Create data volumes. Optionally mount them somewhere temporary (`/mnt`) if you need to copy data from the old location. mount them permantly in fstab, ideally identifying volumes by stable names like LABEL or UUID.

Behavior of EC2 root devices is well documented. A benefit of data volumes is not being a root device implies unlikely to be automatically deleted. Test instance termination on less-important instances. If this deletes an important volume, test your backup restore processes too. Do not fear unknown behavior or change, that is what test environments and a business continuity plan are for.

Size of the OS device can be double-digit GB.